# VBOs slower than obsolete method of drawing primitives - why?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, graphics, vbo

I'm working on a Tile-based OpenGL, C++ application. 
I'm adding sample screen from application, so that it will be more clear:

[image]

I have `Tile` class which contains an array of `Object`s. Each tile can store up to 15 objects - the example of that is `Tile` with green and yellow square on it (two objects), so it's 10x10x15 = 1500 `Object`s to draw (in the worst case, because I'm not handling 'empty' ones). Usually it's less, in my testings I use around 600 of them. `Object` has it's own graphic, that can be drawn. Each `Object` belongs to one `Tile` at a time, but it can be moved (as for example red squares in the picture).

`Object`s backgrounds are going to have a border and they need to be nicely scalable, so I'm using 9-patch pattern to draw them (they are made of 9 quads).

Without drawing `Tile`s (their `Object`s to be precise), my application has around `600 fps`.

At first, I've been using obsolete method to draw those `Tile`s - using `glBegin(GL_QUADS)`/`glEnd()` and `glDisplayList`s. I had a big drop of performance due to that drawing - from `600` to `320 fps`. This is how I've been drawing them:

```
bool Background::draw(const TPoint& pos, int width, int height)
{
    if(width <= 0 || height <= 0)
        return false;
    //glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef((GLfloat)pos.x, (GLfloat)pos.y, 0.0f);     // Move background to right direction
    if((width != m_savedWidth) || (height != m_savedHeight))    // If size to draw is different than the one saved in display list,
        // then recalculate everything and save in display list
    {
        // That size will be now saved in display list
        m_savedWidth = width;
        m_savedHeight = height;

        // If this background doesn't have unique display list id specified yet,
        // then let OpenGL generate one
        if(m_displayListId == NO_DISPLAY_LIST_ID)
        {
            GLuint displayList;
            displayList = glGenLists(1);
            m_displayListId = displayList;
        }

        glNewList(m_displayListId, GL_COMPILE);

        GLfloat texelCentersOffsetX = (GLfloat)1/(2*m_width);

        // Instead of coordinates range 0..1 we need to specify new ones
        GLfloat maxTexCoordWidth = m_bTiling    ? (GLfloat)width/m_width    :   1.0;
        GLfloat maxTexCoordHeight = m_bTiling   ? (GLfloat)height/m_height  :   1.0;

        GLfloat maxTexCoordBorderX = (GLfloat)m_borderWidth/m_width;
        GLfloat maxTexCoordBorderY = (GLfloat)m_borderWidth/m_height;

        /* 9-cell-pattern

        -------------------
        | 1 |    2    | 3 |
        -------------------
        |   |         |   |
        | 4 |    9    | 5 |
        |   |         |   |
        -------------------
        | 6 |    7    | 8 |
        -------------------

        */

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);               // Select Our Texture

        // Top left quad [1]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2i(0, 0);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 0.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);
        glEnd();

        // Top middle quad [2]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX + texelCentersOffsetX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX + texelCentersOffsetX, 0.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX - texelCentersOffsetX, 0.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX - texelCentersOffsetX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);
        glEnd();

        // Top right quad [3]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, 0.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + width, 0);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width, 0 + m_borderWidth);
        glEnd();

        // Middle left quad [4]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY );
            glVertex2i(0, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0, maxTexCoordBorderY );
            glVertex2i(0, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY );
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY );
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);
        glEnd();

        // Middle right quad [5]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);
        glEnd();

        // Bottom left quad [6]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(0, 0 + height);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + height);
        glEnd();

        // Bottom middle quad [7]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX + texelCentersOffsetX, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + height);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordBorderX + texelCentersOffsetX, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX - texelCentersOffsetX, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX - texelCentersOffsetX, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + height);
        glEnd();

        // Bottom right quad [8]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + height);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f((GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderX, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, (GLfloat)1.0 - maxTexCoordBorderY);
            glVertex2i(0 + width, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(0 + width, 0 + height);
        glEnd();

        GLfloat xTexOffset;
        GLfloat yTexOffset;

        if(m_borderWidth > 0)
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_centerTexture);     // If there's a border, we have to use
            // second texture now for middle quad
            xTexOffset = 0.0;                                  // We are using another texture, so middle middle quad
            yTexOffset = 0.0;                                  // has to be texture with a whole texture
        }
        else
        {
            // Don't bind any texture here - we're still using the same one

            xTexOffset = maxTexCoordBorderX;                   // But it implies using offset which equals
            yTexOffset = maxTexCoordBorderY;                   // maximum texture coordinates
        }

        // Middle middle quad [9]
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f(xTexOffset, maxTexCoordHeight - yTexOffset);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);

            // Top left
            glTexCoord2f(xTexOffset, yTexOffset);
            glVertex2i(0 + m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Top right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - xTexOffset, yTexOffset);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + m_borderWidth);

            // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f(maxTexCoordWidth - xTexOffset, maxTexCoordHeight - yTexOffset);
            glVertex2i(0 + width - m_borderWidth, 0 + height - m_borderWidth);
        glEnd();

        glEndList();
    }

    glCallList(m_displayListId); // Now we can call earlier or now created display list

    glPopMatrix();

    return true;
}
```

There is probably too much of code there, but I wanted to show everything. The main thing about this version is use of display lists and `glVertex2i` which are deprecated.

I thought the problem of such slow down was use of this obsolete method which I read is quite slow, so I decided to go for `VBO`. I've used [this tutorial](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_vbo.html) and according to it I changed my method like this:

```
bool Background::draw(const TPoint& pos, int width, int height)
{
    if(width <= 0 || height <= 0)
        return false;

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef((GLfloat)pos.x, (GLfloat)pos.y, 0.0f);             // Move background to right direction
    if((width != m_savedWidth) || (height != m_savedHeight))        // If size to draw is different than the one saved in display list,
                                                                    // then recalculate everything and save in display list
    {
        // That size will be now saved in display list
        m_savedWidth = width;
        m_savedHeight = height;

        GLfloat texelCentersOffsetX = (GLfloat)1/(2*m_width);

        // Instead of coordinates range 0..1 we need to specify new ones
        GLfloat maxTexCoordWidth = m_bTiling    ? (GLfloat)width/m_width    :   1.0;
        GLfloat maxTexCoordHeight = m_bTiling   ? (GLfloat)height/m_height  :   1.0;

        GLfloat maxTexCoordBorderX = (GLfloat)m_borderWidth/m_width;
        GLfloat maxTexCoordBorderY = (GLfloat)m_borderWidth/m_height;

        /* 9-cell-pattern, each number represents one quad

        -------------------
        | 1 |    2    | 3 |
        -------------------
        |   |         |   |
        | 4 |    9    | 5 |
        |   |         |   |
        -------------------
        | 6 |    7    | 8 |
        -------------------

        */

        /* How vertices are distributed on one quad made of two triangles

        v1 ------ v0
        |       /  |
        |     /    |
        |  /       |
        v2 ------ v3

        */

        GLfloat vertices[] = { 
                                // Top left quad [1]
                                m_borderWidth, 0, 0,                            // v0
                                0, 0, 0,                                        // v1       
                                0, m_borderWidth, 0,                            // v2               

                                0, m_borderWidth, 0,                            // v2
                                m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,                // v3
                                m_borderWidth, 0, 0,                            // v0

                                // Top middle quad [2]
                                width-m_borderWidth, 0, 0,                      // v0
                                m_borderWidth, 0, 0,                            // v1
                                m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,                // v2

                                m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,                // v2
                                width-m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,          // v3
                                width-m_borderWidth, 0, 0,                      // v0

                                // Top right quad [3]
                                width, 0, 0,                                    // v0  
                                width-m_borderWidth, 0, 0,                      // v1
                                width-m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,          // v2

                                width-m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,          // v2
                                width, m_borderWidth, 0,                        // v3
                                width, 0, 0,                                    // v0

                                // Middle left quad [4]
                                m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,                // v0
                                0, m_borderWidth, 0,                            // v1
                                0, height-m_borderWidth, 0,                     // v2

                                0, height-m_borderWidth, 0,                     // v2
                                m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,         // v3
                                m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,                // v0

                                // Middle right quad [5]
                                width, m_borderWidth, 0,                        // v0
                                width-m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,          // v1
                                width-m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,   // v2

                                width-m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,   // v2
                                width, height-m_borderWidth, 0,                 // v3
                                width, m_borderWidth, 0,                        // v0

                                // Bottom left quad [6]
                                m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,         // v0
                                0, height-m_borderWidth, 0,                     // v1
                                0, height, 0,                                   // v2

                                0, height, 0,                                   // v2
                                m_borderWidth, height, 0,                       // v3
                                m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,         // v0

                                // Bottom middle quad [7]
                                width-m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,   // v0
                                m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,         // v1
                                m_borderWidth, height, 0,                       // v2

                                m_borderWidth, height, 0,                       // v2
                                width-m_borderWidth, height, 0,                 // v3
                                width-m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,   // v0

                                // Bottom right quad [8]
                                width, height-m_borderWidth, 0,                 // v0
                                width-m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,   // v1
                                width-m_borderWidth, height, 0,                 // v2

                                width-m_borderWidth, height, 0,                 // v2
                                width, height, 0,                               // v3
                                width, height-m_borderWidth, 0,                 // v0

                                // Middle middle quad [9]
                                width-m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,          // v0
                                m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0,                // v1
                                m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,         // v2

                                m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,         // v2
                                width-m_borderWidth, height-m_borderWidth, 0,   // v3
                                width-m_borderWidth, m_borderWidth, 0           // v0
                            };

        copy(vertices, vertices + 162, m_vCoords);              // 162, because we have 162 coordinates 


        int dataSize = 162 * sizeof(GLfloat);
        m_vboId = createVBO(m_vCoords, dataSize);

    }

    // bind VBOs for vertex array
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, m_vboId);          // for vertex coordinates

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                   // activate vertex coords array
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);                     
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 162);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);                  // deactivate vertex array

    // bind with 0, so, switch back to normal pointer operation
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, NO_VBO_ID);

    glPopMatrix();

    return true;
}
```

It is quite similar to previous version, but instead of `glDisplayList` and `glVertex2i()` I used `VBO` which is being created from data stored in an array.

But results disappointed me, because I got performance drop instead of boost, I got barely
 `~260 fps` and I must note that in this method version I haven't yet implemented use of textures, so there are only quads for now without any texture bound to it.

I've read a few articles to find what could be the reason of such slow down and found out that maybe it is due to big amount of small `VBO`s and I should probably have one `VBO` containing all backgrounds data instead of separate `VBO` for each background. But the problem is that `Object`s can move around and they have different textures (and texture atlas is not a good solution for me), so it would be difficult for me to update those changes for those `Object`s that changed their state. For now, when `Object`s is being changed, I just recreate it's `VBO` and the rest `VBO`s stay untouched.

So my question is - what am I doing wrong? Does using bigger (~600) number of small `VBO`s is really slower than obsolete method of drawing with `glVertex2i`? And what could be - maybe not the best, but better - solution in my case?

Comment: Frames-per-second is a [terrible comparative metric](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/fps_versus_frame_time.htm).  Switch to (milli-)seconds per frame.

Comment: @genpfault Thank you, it's definitely good to know that. The fact remains that VBO is slower in that case, though.

Comment: Some drivers are actually very good at compiling display lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because the fixed-function stuff is old, deprecated, and generally not recommended, does not necessarily mean it is always slow.

Nor does the fancy 'new' (it's been around a while) functionality with buffers and shaders and such-like necessarily mean that everything will be lightning fast.

When you wrap your drawing in a display list, you are basically passing off a bunch of operations to the driver. This actually gives a fair bit of scope for the driver to optimise what is happening. It may very well package most of what you're doing up into a pretty efficient pre-packaged lump of GPU operations. That may well be slightly more efficient than what happens when *you* package up your data into buffers and send them off.

That isn't to say that I would recommend sticking with the old-style interface, but certainly I'm not surprised that there are cases where it does a good job.

Answer (score 7):

By the looks of it, you're recreating the VBO with every frame. If you just want to change the data use `glBufferSubData`, as `glBufferData` goes through the whole, lengthy VBO initialization.

If the data is static, create the VBO only once, then reuse it.

Comment: Note that if you want to have a VBO with data that changes a lot, you should use GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW as the data type for the VBO.

Comment: This looks to be precisely the issue. Move your VBO creation code into a different method (such as `createMesh`) and only call it when a new object is needed (such as initialization). Recreating the VBO every frame nulls any gain from employing it.

Comment: VBO is not being recreated every frame - only if the size of drawing object is being changed, which happens very rarely.

Comment: I don't see why the VBO should be changed just for scaling - just scale the model matrix (glScalef or whatever).